# Why does this question show up in the [developers] search results?

Tags: support, locked-questions, tag-search

**UPDATE**

The tag has been burned; the locked question is no longer on the list.

---

Or maybe that should be, "*Questions with mod-removed tags show up on that tag's search results*"...

I went and did a [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developers) for [developers], and saw that [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/16137/timeline) post still shows up in the results even though the [developers] tag was edited out.  It's locked, so a moderator [had to remove the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/16137/timeline#history_24012fba-4763-46ff-b2af-f3e6333873f5), but it still shows on the list.  It doesn't have that tag anymore, so it shouldn't be there.

Is this normal behavior, or a brief glitch?

Comment: That can't be brief, it's been there for hours...

Comment: I believe it has something to do with how historical locks work. Of note here is that the tag was removed *after* the lock was applied. I noticed this before but I imagined that it wasn't going to matter once the tag was fully burninated. It doesn't actually *have* the tag, so that shouldn't mess with the burnination process... Right? Hopefully?

Comment: @Spevacus Only one way to find out... if it does, I'll limber up me [bug]-writing muscles.

Comment: @Spevacus See the edit.

Comment: Weird. Very weird. I wonder if a mod unlocked it and relocked it if it would disappear from the search results. Either way, the tag is gone.

Comment: Caching? its always caching....

Comment: @Journeyman Caching is evil... it didn't show up on the SE-network search, why on Meta?

Comment: One word. Caching! Maybe different search indexes?