# Locked posts not showing up in search - is this intentional?

Tags: discussion, search, locked-questions

Forwarding [this bug report](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22001/68942) from CGCC meta:

We have a meta tag [best-of](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), which is an annual category for our site. It's basically a competition, and so we have a meta post to vote for nominations. The voting post gets locked for historical significance after voting is done, most likely to lock the votes in place more than it being off-topic.

However, when searching for this tag, these posts don't show up, even though it would be better (for our site) that they do. Searching with `is:q` makes them show up though.

My question is: is it intentional that locked posts don't show up? The only discussion I can find relating to this here is [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60747/please-keep-closed-locked-posts-from-showing-up-in-searches) asking for closed/locked posts to be hidden, which would imply that they once did show up, and there is no indication that this change actually went through.

If so, is there a way to change it per site (since we have a good amount of posts that are locked but that people will want to search for)?

Comment: Related, but the inverse: [Why does this question show up in the \[developers\] search results?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362708/295232) – which can't be reproduced anymore.

Comment: Tag searches explicitly exclude historically locked posts. I... am looking for where it actually says that, though. As a note, that question already has a status-review tag on it - so posting it here is unnecessary. We will respond when we get to it.

Comment: @Catija Closest I could get is https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/ : *"For now, we’ve provided a “Historical Artifact” lock that completely freezes a question and its answers, preventing all further editing, voting, answering, and flagging. It will also remove it from the usual lists of questions on the site while allowing it to remain fully accessible and visible to everyone with a link to it."*. If searches count as 'usual lists of questions' :/

Comment: @Tinkeringbell The [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/) says: "*Additionally, on main (non-meta) sites, historically locked questions are omitted from normal question lists (those on the home page, /questions, and the various per-tag lists), but can still be found by searching for words in the post or title (via either site-search or Google, etc) or by using the search operator locked:1.*" But uh... it seems to indicate it's supposed to exclude meta - but it clearly doesn't. And as far as I'm aware, this is not a new "bug"... I don't know that it ever worked properly.

Comment: Shog added that in 2012 but I know that the historically locked posts on M&TV meta never showed up in searches at all - I remember struggling to find them. :/ So that may have been intended but I'm not sure it actually *works*.

Comment: @Catija Yeah, I was looking at that too... I was about to say it may have never been noticed until now, [but...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354355/369802)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Hard for people to notice something that's very rare on most sites. :P Or to even know that it's an issue. Even though I've read that historical lock FAQ several times, it wasn't until today that I even realized meta was supposed to be special-cased at all.

Comment: @Catija Same... you learn something new here every day :D

Comment: As the FAQ says, historically-locked posts are supposed to be hidden from search results, but that isn't supposed to happen on meta sites. I've already asked about this at [Are historically-locked questions supposed to be hidden on meta sites now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354355/are-historically-locked-questions-supposed-to-be-hidden-on-meta-sites-now) (@Catija)